# Using AverageIf function on large amount of cells does not behave as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that I'm fooling around with attempting to analyze data.  I could go the pivot table route possibly, but I like being stubborn and building my own formulas/tables to analyze the data sometimes.

---

Anyways my problem is this:
I'm trying to find the average of a column of cells (just one column) that contain 'x' value somewhere in the same row.  Using the function `AverageIf`, I can easily do this 'manually', but I'd like to be able to change the 'x' value by editing another cell.

Currently said code looks like this:

`=AVERAGEIF($D$2:$D$527,L$2,$I$2:$I$527)`.

It works fine.  But it limits what 'x' value I can sort the Average through to only ones within the `D` column.  I attempted to highlight all the data I would potentially be analyzing like so:

`=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$H$527, L$2, $I$2:$I$527)`

That just gives me all sorts of issues.  I'm obviously not utilizing the `If` function correctly here, is there anyway to fix this error or am I stuck analyzing column by column for different 'x' values.

---

Side note, 'x' values are all string text, not an actual digit.  Not sure if that makes a difference.  And I am attempting to make a small table with this data (not an actual excel `table`), hence the `$` in the formulas, as I'm using the `fill` option.  There are just a ton of different comparisons I could potentially make and I don't like limiting myself.

Also, when I used `fill` to move this formula over one column, I have a completely different error from the above formula.  In the first case, the output is a `.` .
In the second case the output is a `#div/0` error.  Only difference in the two formula's is the `criteria` portion.

The actual code for the second `filled` formula:

`=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$H$527, M$2, $I$2:$I$527)`

Though the output is changing based upon the 'x' value.  Some work fine after testing a few, most give me issues.

---

EDIT: Playing around with this for a bit, weird stuff keeps happening.  I find it depends where on the 'table' I set up matters to how the average is calculated.  In other words, an 'x' value that doesn't work in the first column of my analyzing table will work perfectly fine elsewhere in the table, but only if certain other values are selected in the other spaces of the table. If that doesn't make sense in how I described it, let me know.

EDIT 2: Just going to throw up the data set, [DropBox Excel File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uma2cvgounbhss/New%20Microsoft%20Excel%20Worksheet.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: It might be helpful if you include sampme data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I might as well throw up the data set, it's nothing important.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen dont' know if you'd be willing to help or were just giving me some advice to get more answers, but uploaded the excel file linked above.

Comment: Maybe try to include a minimal sample in the actual question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I actually attempted that, but the problem didn't exist in the minimal sample set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when using a multi-column range as the first parameter, the "value" range (Col I) in your example gets shifted to the right, according to the location on each row where the "criteria" value is matched.

Simple example:

[image]

Using "A" as the criteria get the average from ColF as expected, but using "B" or "C" gets the average from cols G and H respectively.

I think in some cases you're actually averaging numbers in your "analysis" block (which in your posted file is to the right of your data block).